# Send email from main domain using exim4

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, exim

I've installed exim4 on my server to send email for server messages, registration messages, lost password messages etc.

My server's FQDN/rDNS is mail.example.com, which I also entered during the configuration of exim4 (`dpkg-reconfigure exim4`).

Emails are now sent from addresses like notification@mail.example.com. How can I change this to just notification@example.com?

I'm afraid that if I just enter example.com during exim4's configuration my emails will be marked as spam.

I do have a SPF record.

Comment: Could you include your configuration?  An Exim expert will likely know some things to try without it, but can say for sure if they can see your full configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian, MTAs including Exim4 are configured to get the canonical domain from `/etc/mailname`.  Mail clients (like `mutt`) are also supposed to read this file.

This means that you can have a sensible hostname and still get your mail sent out with your desired `From:` header field.  Beware of having more than one host with the same value in their `/etc/mailname` files, because this means that they will each accept locally generated mail for this domain instead of sending it to the MX.  You can probably edit your MTA config file or use `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` to avoid this.

If you prefer, you can put `export EMAIL=me@example.com` in your `.profile`.  `mutt` will then use it in preference to `/etc/mailname` for the `From:` header field, but will still use the system mailname as the envelope sender.  This is what you want, IMHO.